# Can't Resolve My Promise in Controller - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have a service function that looks like:

```
this.addJobRating = function(jobId, userId, rating){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.post('/to/my/api', {job_id: jobId, user_id: userId, rating: rating})
        .success(function(data){
            deferred.resolve(data)
        })
        .error(function(data){
            deferred.reject('promise call failed');
        });
    return deferred;
};
```

I can call the above in my controller like so

```
console.log(myService.addJobRating(646, 9999, 'good-result')
```

This logs the expected promise object in console log.  But if I try to resolve the promise using:

```
myService.addJobRating(646, 9999, 'good-result').then(function(data){
    console.log(data);
}, function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

I get an `TypeError: undefined is not a function` error.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Leaving the typo apart, why can't you just return the http promise itself? `return $http.post('/to/my/api', {job_id: jobId, user_id: userId, rating: rating}).then(function(resp){ return resp.data;  }, function(data){ return $q.reject('promise call failed'); });`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`myService.addJobRating` should return `deferred.promise`.

Answer (score 3):

You should be returning the promise - `deferred.promise` - from addJobRating, not `deferred`.